# PHP Curl downloads empty file(.gz) from a https URL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download a .xml.gz file from a https URL with authentication.

Here is my current code.

```
    $remote_file = 'https://path/filename.xml.gz';
    $local_file = "test.xml.gz";
    $username ="21";
    $password ="qwerty";

    $ch = curl_init($remote_file);
    $headers = array('Content-type: application/x-gzip','Connection: Close');
    $fp = fopen ($local_file, 'wb');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$remote_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if(fwrite($fp,$data))
    {
     echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "fail";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

After execution, the test.xml.gz file is created but empty.

I think the problem is with getting connected to the file in the https page. The code seem to work fine when I tried downloading a file from a non https url.

strangely, curl shows no error whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After outputting the trace using curl verbose, I found the problem was with the $headers. Apparently,removing $headers and replacing with  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true) worked as expected.

Here's the final code.

```
$fp = fopen($local_file, 'wb');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remote_file);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$write = fwrite($fp,$result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result from curl_exec in to a variable:

```
$fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then write the contents of the file to your local file:

```
fwrite($fp, $fileContents);
```

Then it should work as desired.

Comment: Hi, I tried that too. didn't seem to work. I have updated the code in the question details

Comment: If you output the contents of $data what do you get? Also, see if you're getting a curl error using curl_error($ch) would be a good bet.

Comment: echoing $data displays 1 and curl_error($ch)  shows no error at all

Comment: As a test, can you remove the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); line? As that should've written to the file, but let's see if it's getting the data back when it runs curl_exec().

Comment: In that case, $data is empty. it doesn't echo anything. I'm pretty sure the URL to the file is correct as I'm able to download directly from the browser.